# How to share an instance variable between files in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm trying to build a Telegram bot, I'm using the following npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-telegram-bot-api

I have the following project structure:

[image: project structure]

In my `app.js` file I do: `const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});`. I would like to share this `bot` instance with the `index.js` files, so that in the `index.js` files I can do something like:

```
bot.onText(/\/time (.+)/, (msg, match) => {

});
```

I'm not sure how I can acomplish this, the only way I can think of is doing this by using module.exports on app.js file, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way of doing it.

**-edit-**

In the app.js file I want to do:

```
require('./plugins/time')
require('./plugins/weather')
```

and then type `node app.js` to run the bot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the correct way. The usual one.

Also there is global variables but they are evil, so you shouldn't use them.

Simply export your variable through exports.